# Injective on a dense set

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X\to Y$ a continuous function between Hausdorff spaces such that $D\subseteq X$ is dense and $f\restriction_D$ is injective. Can we say that $f$ must be injective?

I can't find a counterexample, so I tried to prove it:

Let $x,y\in X$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. If $x\neq y$, then there exist $U,V\subseteq X$ disjoint open sets with $x\in U$ and $y\in V$. We know that $D$ intersects both $U$ and $V$, but now I don't know what to do.

What do you think?

Comment: $X=[0,1]$, $D=(0,1)$ and $f:X\to S^1$, $f(x)=e^{2i\pi x}$. Here $f$ is injective on $D$ but not on the points $\{0,1\}$, both are mapped to $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $D=\mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=|\sqrt 2x|+x$.

> Assume $f(x)=f(y)$ with $x\ne y$. Since $f\restriction_{[0,\infty)}$ and $f\restriction_{(-\infty,0]}$ are injective, we need only consider the case $x<0<y$, so $(1-\sqrt2)x=(1+\sqrt 2)y$ and hence $\frac xy=\frac{1+\sqrt 2}{1-\sqrt 2}=-3-2\sqrt 2$ is not rational, i.e. $x,y$ cannot be both in $D$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Hagen. I was thinking if there exists another condition on $X$ or $Y$ such that this result is true, but maybe there isn't such a condition.

Answer (score 3):

- Let $X=[0,2\pi]$, $Y=$the unit circle, $D=[0,2\pi)$, and $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$.
- Let $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $D=\mathbb Q$, and $f(x)=x^3-2x$.  See more at [If polynomial with rational number is injective on rationals then it is injective on reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436487/if-polynomial-with-rational-number-is-injective-on-rationals-then-it-is-injectiv).

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x$ if $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(2)=1$. Take $D=[0,1)\cup\{2\}$.